# Good way to implement a normalize filter in numpy

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I'm not so familiar with the memory model of Numpy arrays. Is there a more efficient way (or a 'better practice' way) of computing a normalized version of an image? That is, the image such that for each pixel `r+g+b == 1`.

Using a more matrix oriented approach perhaps? Does such a filter have a name?

Here is the code that I have so far (ignoring divide by zero errors):

```
def normalize(image):
    lines, columns, depth = image.shape
    normalized = np.zeros(image.shape)
    for i in range(lines):
            for j in range(columns):
                    normalized[i,j] = image[i,j] / float(np.sum(image[i,j]))
    return normalized
```

Where image is a `np.array` of depth 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be done much more efficiently taking advantage of numpy's [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> image = np.random.random(size=(3,4,5))
>>> sums = image.sum(axis=2)
>>> sums.shape
... (3, 4)
>>> normalized  = image / sums[:, :, None] #same as image / sums[:, :, np.newaxis]
>>> normalized.sum(axis=2)
... array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
...        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
...        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

If you're worried about memory, and don't need the original image you can normalize it in-place

```
>>> image /= image.sum(axis=2)[:, :, None]
```

As a function:

```
def normalize(image, inplace=False):
    if inplace:
        image /= image.sum(axis=2)[:, :, None]
    else:
        return image / image.sum(axis=2)[:, :, None]
```

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I meant. Note that one might want to use `np.float64(image)` to avoid integer division.